# Blazor - component displays once then doesn't show again

Tags: c#, blazor

I have created a 'toaster' component. It is used to display errors and success. In general, my component will show as expected in either case if the message is only to be displayed once. i.e. on a round trip to the server to display success or failure.

I'm now trying to use the same component for client side validation. The first time I raise an error my component displays, but anytime after that it will not I've placed `StateHasChanged()` in a number of places and it doesn't seem to help.

when there is a success, then the toaster goes away after 3 seconds. If it's a failure then it stays on screen until the user closes it.

Here is my component:

```
<div class="toast @toastClass" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">

<div class="toast-header">
    <strong class="me-auto">@toastHeader</strong>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close" @onclick="()=>ToastClose()"></button>
</div>
<div class="toast-body">
    @toastMessage
</div>

</div>
```

and the code behind:

```
public partial class Toaster
{
private System.Timers.Timer timer;


[Parameter]
public string toastClass { get; set; } = "hide";

[Parameter]
public string toastHeader { get; set; } = "Success";
[Parameter]
public string toastMessage { get; set; } = "Succesfully saved!";

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (toastClass != "hide")
        StartTimer(3000);
}

public void StartTimer(double interval)
{
    
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
    timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsedHandler;
    timer.Start();
   
}

private void TimerElapsedHandler(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
    if (toastClass != "show toast-error")
        ToastClose();
  //  StateHasChanged();
}

protected void ToastClose()
{
    toastClass = "hide";
}
}
```

When I use the toaster:

In my page I have:

```
 <Toaster toastHeader=@toastHeader toastMessage=@toastMessage toastClass=@toastClass></Toaster>
```

and then in my page code behind I have a method that does some validation and sets, the error if needed:

```
......
 if (RemainingCartons != 0) 
 {
      errMsg.AppendLine("Remaining cartons are not allocated correctly.");
 }

 if (RemainingUnits != 0)
 {
     errMsg.AppendLine("Remaining units are not allocated correctly.");
 }
 if (RemainingGOHSets != 0)
 {
     errMsg.AppendLine("Remaining GOH Sets are not allocated correctly.");
 }

 if (RemainingGOHUnits != 0)
 {
     errMsg.AppendLine("Remaining GOH Units are not allocated correctly.");
 }

 if (errMsg.ToString() != string.Empty && errMsg != null)
 {
     toastHeader = "Error";
     toastMessage = errMsg.ToString();
     toastClass = "show toast-error";
    
     return false;
 }....
```

The first time through this bit of code, the toaster displays the correct error message and I close the toaster manually. I make a change that is still going to cause an error, The code path again goes down this path, sets the correct error message, but the toaster doesn't show. When I look in the browser, my compoent still has `hide` set against it's class. I've tried adding `StateHasChanged()` before the `return false` line and in the component itself makes no difference. The `OnParametersSetAsync` method of the component does not get triggered again after the first time the component displays the message. Can anybody spot what I've missed.

Comment: Personally, I'd not communicate directly with the `Toast` component as a child, and would not use any of its lifecycle events in this way.  I'd make it independent, and use a service with a method to "send" new toasts, and I'd place the component in the main Layout page, so that any page that wants to use it can just `@inject ToastService TS`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the code.

1. You should *never* write to the `[Parameter]` from inside the component. So, do not update `toastClass` from inside `<Toaster>` Check this guidance from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0
2. You are overriding `OnParameterSetAsync` but there is no awaitable task inside. So it will simply run. You should use async-await in blazor to change state of the component based on a timed task.
   So you might want to change it to

> ```
> protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
> {
>     if (toastClass != "hide")
>     {
>       showing = true;
>       await Task.Delay(3000);
>       toastClass = "hide"; 
>       showing = false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Added the showing flag in case you want to simply add a condition if(showing) instead of css class "hide". Chuck the Timer and related methods altogether.

Comment: I have taken both answers on board : changed my casing and am not using the parameters directly. This still didn't resolve the issue.  I created an event callback in the component that gets invoked on `ToastClose()`. In the parent page I then clear the parent variables that get passed to the component.  Now the toaster displays every time the user causes an error, even if it's still the same error. Not sure why setting these empty in a callback works, but calling `StatusHasChanged()` after setting them in a non-async method doesn't.

Comment: StateHasChanged in a non async method doesn't work for some reason. Try InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)

Answer (score 0):

> I've placed StateHasChanged() in a number of places and it doesn't seem to help.

It won't.  With well structured logic, there are very few circumstances where you need to call `StateHasChanged`.

> Can anybody spot what I've missed?

As has already been stated in the other answers, there are many issues with your current implementation.

My answer takes the liberty of refactoring your code.  See the inline comments for details on what each bit of code does.  Note there are no calls to `StateHasChanged`.

The code uses the component bind framework to control the displayed message.  `null` = nothing to display.

```cs
@implements IDisposable 
@using System.Timers;

<div class="toast @_toastClass" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">

    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto">@this.ToastHeader</strong>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close" @onclick="()=>ToastClose()"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        @this.Message
    </div>

</div>
@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new Timer(3000);

    private bool _display => this.Message is not null;
    private bool _isRunning;
    private string? _currentMessage;

    private string _toastClass => _display ? "show" : "hide";

    [Parameter] public string ToastHeader { get; set; } = "Success";
    [Parameter] public string Message { get; set; } = "Succesfully saved!";
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> MessageChanged { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Set up the timer once and then reuse
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsedHandler;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Check if the message has updated while we are displating the current message
        // If so reset the timer
        if (_currentMessage != Message && _isRunning)
        {
            _currentMessage = Message;
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        // Check if we have a new valid message to display
        // If we do start the timer and set the running flag
        if (_display && !_isRunning)
        {
            _currentMessage = this.Message;
            _isRunning = true;
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private async Task ToastClose()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        await this.ClearMessage();
    }

    private async void TimerElapsedHandler(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        // Need to invoke on the Synchronisation Context Thread
        await this.InvokeAsync(ClearMessage);
    }

    private async Task ClearMessage()
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        _currentMessage = null;
        await this.MessageChanged.InvokeAsync(null);
    }

    // unhook the event handler and clean up
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= TimerElapsedHandler;
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Index:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Clicked">Update</button>
</div>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

 <Toaster ToastHeader=@_toastHeader @bind-Message="_toastMessage"></Toaster>

@code {
    private string? _toastMessage;
    private string? _toastHeader = "MyHeader";

    private void Clicked()
        => _toastMessage = $"Clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
 }
```

Comment: Personally I would do as @Benny1973 suggests and use a service based system.  Search for examples on the Internet.